# How do you terminate threading using Pyinput

Tags: python, multithreading, keyboard

I realize this question has been asked many times but I have a very difficult time understanding threading and with statement and consequently I cannot understand the other answers given.  I was able to accomplish this task about 5 years ago but my threading skills have since fallen into disuse.  In any case, I'm trying to register the x,y coordinates of a mouse click, store the values to a global, then terminate the keyboard listener, then do other things.  In the code below, I cannot get the code to advance to where it says `p("done")`, even after I press the 'e' button.  When I pause the code and analyse the values of the `done` variable it will output 1 so I don't understand why the code is not advancing to the next line.  Again, I want to iterate to please not assume that I understand what you're saying when you talk about `threading` or `with` statements.  I have only a very vague notion of what these things do.

```
from pynput import keyboard, mouse

done = 0
xa = 0
ya = 0
p = print

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global xa, ya
    print (x,y)
    xa = x
    ya = y

def on_press(key):
    global done
    if key.char == 'e':
        done = 1

def listen():
    global done
    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as kl, \
            mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click) as ml:
        kl.join()
        ml.join()
        while 1:
            if done:
                p ('done')
                kl.terminate()
                ml.terminate()
                p ('you did it')
                return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick research: There should be stop conditions in mouse's `on_click` and keyboard's `on_release`. `on_release` is not presented in your example but the keyboard listener needs it implemented to accurately stop listening.

I've changed the example a bit. Notice the lines where I put the comment "# Stop listener". They are simply a branching statement.

```py
from pynput import keyboard, mouse

done = 0
xa = 0
ya = 0
p = print


def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global xa, ya
    print(x, y)
    xa = x
    ya = y
    if not pressed:
        # Stop listener
        return False


def on_press(key):
    global done
    try:
        if key.char == "e":
            done = 1
    except:
        pass


def on_release(key):
    try:
        if key.char == "e":
            # Stop listener
            return False
    except:
        pass


def listen():
    global done
    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as kl, \
        mouse.Listener(on_click=on_click) as ml:
        kl.join()
        ml.join()
        while 1:
            if done:
                p("done")
                kl.stop() # .terminate() is incorrect
                ml.stop() # .terminate() is incorrect
                p("you did it")
                return


listen()
```